# Pass Observable result to another endless Observable

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, pojo

I'm totally new to RxJava and I want to achieve something that should be easy enough but I can't seem to wrap my head around yet.

I have a Retrofit call that returns an Observable with a list of my POJO. And then if there are more calls to make, it asks for another list, and after some time I might want to ask another list.

```
result.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ pojoArray: ArrayList<POJO> ->
                //TODO: pass the results on to other observable
                if (pojoArray.size == pageSize) {
                   //array is full, there is more pages to call
                   //call Retrofit again for more POJO
                }
            }
```

Every time I want to call the Retrofit call it returns me a new Observable which I subscribe to to get the ArrayList

What I want to do then, is to have another Observable, that external clients can observe and receive a transparent stream of POJO. So every time the Retrofit returns me the ArrayList, I want to push all objects from the list to this Observable with an endless stream o POJO.

How do I create the endless Observable that I can push POJO objects to every time I receive a response from Retrofit?

Comment: See [`PublishSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html)  and [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-and-async-subject-224d663d452f) for example.